# botium cli doesnt start on windows server - eperm operation not allowed

Tags: windows, npm, server, chatbot

Installed nodejs and npm on my windows server.
Ran the command `npm install -g botium-cli`
Then uploaded the working botium.json and convo files.

It is a fresh installation. Am I required to change any settings?

When starting botium the following error appears:

C:\Users\Administrator>botium-cli run
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:1133
      else throw err
           ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Application Data'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:790:3)
    at GlobSync._readdir (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\glob\sync.js:288:41)
    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\glob\sync.js:267:20)
    at GlobSync._readdir (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\glob\sync.js:276:17)
    at GlobSync._processReaddir (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\glob\sync.js:137:22)
    at GlobSync._process (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\glob\sync.js:132:10)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\glob\sync.js:380:10)
    at GlobSync._process (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\glob\sync.js:383:10)
    at GlobSync._process (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to hand over the folder where you placed your convo files as command line parameter (--convos ...). otherwise it will by default assume it is the current directory and do a full recursive scan to detect convo files. In the Windows user directory this will fail.

Alternatively:
Create folder C:\botium - place all convo files and botium.json there. Then do `cd C:\botium` and `botium-cli run`